# comparing 2 vector when the difference is very small

Tags: r

I am trying to compare LHS to RHS in R between two vectors or if the difference is less than 1e-10 but I get into problems when RHS is negative

A2 %*% beta <= b2

Please see the code below

```
   A2 <- matrix(c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), nrow = 1) # Lhs
   b2 <- matrix(-12, nrow = 1) # Rhs

   beta1 <- c(-12.194608285, 0.194608285, 0.002113886, -4.514099372, 0.260898524, -0.004513579)

   > (lhs2 <- A2 %*% beta1)
        [,1]
  [ 1,]  -12
   > (lhs2[abs(lhs2 - b2) < 1e-12] <- 0L)
     [1] 0
   > lhs2 - b2 <= 1e-12
          [,1]
     [1,] FALSE
```

I have no idea why I get FALSE when it suppose to be true.

Comment: After you changed the `lhs2` to 0, then `0 - -12` is. 12.

Comment: @akrun Yes I change it to zero and I am not sure if this what I have to do or not. All what I want is when I multiple A %*% beta get something smaller than b2 or if I take the difference between them is very small number. In this case lhs2 is bigger than b2 but if lhs2 is smaller then I have to take the last difference.